# How do I write sql without subqueries for the following query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT C.pid
FROM Catalog C, Suppliers S
WHERE S.sname = ‘Yosemite Sham’ AND C.sid = S.sid
AND C.cost ≥ ALL (Select C2.cost
FROM Catalog C2, Suppliers S2
 WHERE S2.sname = ‘Yosemite Sham’ AND C2.sid = S2.sid)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3):

First, learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Then, if you assume that the maximum cost occurs only once, you can do:

```
SELECT C.pid
FROM Catalog C JOIN
     Suppliers S
     ON C.sid = S.sid
WHERE S.sname = 'Yosemite Sham'
ORDER BY  c.Cost DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ;
```

Note that the last clause is ANSI standard SQL.  Some databases use other methods for the same functionality.

Without this assumption, basically all reasonable methods use a subquery.  Here is one that doesn't:

```
SELECT C.pid
FROM Catalog C JOIN
     Suppliers S
     ON C.sid = S.sid LEFT JOIN
     Catalog C2
     ON C2.sid = C.sid AND
        C2.Cost > C.Cost
WHERE S.sname = 'Yosemite Sham' AND c2.Cost IS NULL
ORDER BY c.Cost DESC;
```

Note:  This assumes that `sid` is 1-1 with `sname`.  That is a convenience (which is likely to be true) and helps avoid an extra join to `Suppliers`.